# Factor to integer on columns that don't all contain the same levels

Tags: r, data.table

I have 150k columns of 105 million entries which are either `"none", "01", "12", "2+"`. Unfortunately not all columns contain all of the factors.

e.g.

```
df <- data.frame(x1 = rep(c("none", "12", "2+"), each = 5),
                 x2 = rep(c("none", "01", "12"), each = 5)) %>% 
  data.table::as.data.table()
```

so if I do

```
df$x1<-as.integer(as.factor(df$x1))
```

I get the same as

```
df$x2<-as.integer(as.factor(df$x2))
```

which isn't what I'm after.

So I could do:

```
require(magrittr)
df$x1<-factor(df$x1,levels = c("none","01","12","2+")) %>% as.integer()
df$x2<-factor(df$x2,levels = c("none","01","12","2+")) %>% as.integer()
```

And that does the job but I have 150K columns. What is the best way to deal with them as I can't do the above one by one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want to apply on multiple columns use `across`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>%
    mutate(across(everything(), ~
      as.integer(factor(., levels = c("none","01","12","2+"))))
```

---

If we want to ignore the first one, specify the index with `-`

```
df1 <- df %>%
    mutate(across(-1, ~
      as.integer(factor(., levels = c("none","01","12","2+"))))
```

---

Or use `base R`

```
df[] <-  lapply(df, function(x) as.integer(factor(x, levels = c("none","01","12","2+"))))
```

Comment: Wow that was lightening fast, thank you so much! Super small caveat (which I know a quick google would probably useful) but if I don't want to do ALL the columns. Say I wanted to ignore the first one?

Comment: Thank you. I just looked at dplyr and there's a nice explanation of "across", looks super useful! starts_with("Sepal") could be good for me.

Comment: @HCAI Those are just `select_helpers` which can be used when some of the column names have a pattern i.e. prefix/suffix or some other regex with `matches` etc

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `data.table` solution.
With a large data set, instead of calling `names(df)` twice, it might be a good idea to call it just once, assigning the value prior to transforming the `df`'s columns and then using that vector of 150K names.

```
library(data.table)

levs <- c("none","01","12","2+")
df[, (names(df)) := lapply(.SD, factor, levels = levs), .SDcols = names(df)]

identical(levels(df$x1), levels(df$x2))
#[1] TRUE
```

So now use the code above to coerce the levels to integer.

```
df[, (names(df)) := lapply(.SD, function(x){
  as.integer(factor(x, levels = levs))
}), .SDcols = names(df)]
```